# Imprimir Alert PHP

Tags: php, javascript, css, bootstrap

Bom pessoal como consigo imprimir o conteudo de algo do php em uma div por exemplo : 
tenho uma area de login , se os dados do usuario estiverem errado quero que imprima na tela uma div com alert (com bootstrap) na mesma pagina . 
tenho essa validação no php mas quero que me mostre em uma div

segue codigos

login

```
         <form class="login-form" method="POST" action="pg/logar.php">
  <input required type="text" name="f_usuario" placeholder="Usuario"/>
  <input required type="password" name="f_senha" placeholder="Senha"/>
  <button type="submit">Logar</button>
```

logar.php

```
     if($linhas > 0){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
    header("Location:../logado.php");
   }else{
    echo "Dados Digitados Incorretos";
   }
```

Comment: Caso sua pergunta seja diferente da indicada no fechamento, você pode clicar em [edit] e acrescentar partes relevantes que diferenciem o problema. Se realmente forem problemas com soluções diferentes das apontadas no link, pode editar e deixar um comentário para considerarmos a reabertura na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
echo '<div id="alert">Dados Digitados Incorretos</div>';
```

Comment: eu preciso que da minha função logar ele envie Dados digitados incorretos para uma div alert na pagina de login

Comment: Bem, se eu entendi são duas paginas diferentes: uma html, e a outra php. Se você quer que o alert da sua pagina php seja mostrado no seu html fica meio complicado. O que você pode fazer a criar a pagina que você quer que receba o echo, em php ao invés de html, e fazer o require do seu php... assim quando der o erro o alert vai ser exibido normalmente como uma div como na resposta...